# Single instruction push/pop for user stack instead accessory function calls?

Tags: c, stack, machine-instruction

On the processor stack push mov and pop and so on are single instructions.

When compiling source code the compiler generates the single machine instruction version, but during run-time, assuming the stack is ... well a regular stack container, accessing values stored on the stack during run-time takes function calls which translate into tons of machine code.

It is possible to achieve the same level of efficiency for dynamic run-time objects instead of using setter and getter member functions which are way longer than a single machine instruction?

My idea is of using a mark pointer, but I don't know how to literally push its value into a memory location or in from a memory location during run-time without resorting to function calls.

Inlining assembly is probably an option, one I would like to avoid if possible. But I guess I would still have to put it inside a function body so it won't be a single instruction.

Comment: You know that a compiler can inline C functions, right?

Comment: With the right expression of the ideas as functions a really *good* compiler *might* manage it for you out of the box. In-lining will get you most of the way, and most modern compilers do that. Try examining the assembly output of the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is opt out the extra `call` and `ret` from your getters/setters. In this case, you can use the keyword `inline` to tell your compiler to inline that particular function. Another way would be to code your getters/setters using C macro function if they are not too complex.